# HTML table horizontal overflow past div in IE8

Tags: html-table, internet-explorer-8, overflow

I'm building an HTML table that could be at most 5 columns wide and any number long; it rests inside a div.  It looks great in FF/Chrome/Safari, but messes up in IE8:

http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/7209/artistlist.png (I'm a new user so I can't post images directly...)

Here's the code:

```
     <h2 class="blockhead">14 artists found</h2>

    <div class="blockbody">
      <div class="blockrow">
        <font size="+0">
        <div style="max-width: 99.9%;">
        <center><table style="max-width: 99.9%;"><tr>
<td><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=994"><img src="djdb/artist/0/994.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John '00' Fleming</a></center></td>
<td><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=657"><img src="djdb/artist/0/657.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Acquaviva</a></center></td>
<td><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=1120"><img src="djdb/artist/1/1120.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Askew</a></center></td>
<td><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=474"><img src="djdb/artist/0/474.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Dahlbäck</a></center></td>
<td><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=1164"><img src="djdb/artist/1/1164.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Dalagelis</a></center></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=250"><img src="djdb/artist/0/250.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Daly</a></center></td>
<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=935"><img src="djdb/artist/0/935.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Debo</a></center></td>
<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=2"><img src="djdb/artist/0/2.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Digweed</a></center></td>
<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=1132"><img src="djdb/artist/1/1132.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Peel</a></center></td>
<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=338"><img src="djdb/artist/0/338.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Selway</a></center></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=980"><img src="djdb/artist/0/980.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Talabot</a></center></td>
<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=335"><img src="djdb/artist/0/335.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>John Tejada</a></center></td>

<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=863"><img src="djdb/artist/0/863.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>Koen Groeneveld</a></center></td>
<td><br><center><a href="djdb2.php?id=1009"><img src="djdb/artist/1/1009.jpg" style="max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px; border: 2px #414141 solid;" hspace=10><br>Mike Shannon</a></center></td>
</tr></table></center></div>
        </font>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I know it's not pretty, but I'm building this on top of vBulletin so before I edit their code I want to make sure I know exactly what CSS styles I need to edit. I have tried many, many suggestions from Google, and even this site, but nothing has seemed to help IE make the table fit within the div.  Does anybody know how I can do this?  I'm open to trying anything if you're willing to explain something to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed this!  I had to add "table-layout: fixed;" to the table's style, set the table to width=100%, and enclose it inside its own div.

Comment: The flaw of this solution is the table won't automatically arrange the columns' width any more.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly(1), IE8 only supports the max-width CSS if you are running in **Standards Mode** in HTML.

- Do you have a DocType specified?
- Is it an HTML one? XHTML isn't fully supported in IE8

(1) - Just verified, in Quirks Mode (what you get if no DocType is specified), max-width is ignored in IE8.

Comment: I've tried it with and without the max-width CSS piece and it hasn't done much for me.  This is the doctype that is sent in the beginning of the HTML: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Ok, so that is an XHTML doctype which means the max-width will not work on the Div or the Table.  When IE fails to render min/max width/height it usually interprets it as "width"/"height" thus it is likely stretching to almost the full width of the screen.  Can you give us the URL - or provide some additional CSS information/code?  You may find that adding ` align="left"` to the table is the easiest fix.

Comment: Here's the URL: http://www.mercuryserver.com/forums/djdb.php?action=find&item=artist&id=john - I've been playing with the IE8 Developer Tools, and I'm having this problem despite setting the table's width explicitly to via pixel size, cellspacing=0, cellpadding=0, margin=0, padding-bottom,-top,-left,-right=0, overflow, align, etc.

Comment: I finally fixed this!  I had to add "table-layout: fixed;" to the table's style, set the table to width=100%, and enclose it inside its own div.  Thanks for trying to help scun :)